# Where can I find info about the NVidia NV10MGS video card?

Tags: graphics-card, specifications

I want to buy a LENOVO IdeaPad G550A and the specification says it has an NVidia NV10MGS video card, but I can't find any info on this card on Nvidia's site or anywhere else on the net.

Why is that? I thought an nvidia page should turn up with the specifications when I search for it, but there is nothing. Where can I find some info about this card?

Comment: I'd be more concerned with the fact that Lenovo doesn't even list this model on their website. Sounds like an outdated model.

Comment: Well, according to Google the Lenovo G550 was reviewed last August as a new model, so it can't be that outdated:

http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=5205&review=lenovo+g550

Comment: Unfortunately, the model in the review has a different video card, so it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the exact match for a `NVidia NV10MGS`. [nV10 was the codename](http://www.beyond3d.com/resources/chip/2) for one of nVidia's earlier graphics card, (and IMO a classic) - The [GeForce 256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geforce_256). Given that you are looking to purchase a new one, I'm inclined to believe that this is *not quite* the one you're looking at.

Further probing revealed a possible match - The Geforce G1xxM series ( which were introduced rather recently, as rebadged m 9xxx series) *do* have a code name of `N10M-GE`.

So I suspect you are actually looking for reviews of [G105](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-G-105M.13790.0.html)/[G110](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-G-110M.13791.0.html)/[G130M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-130M.13789.0.html) series of chipsets.

Comment: On an other site the model is written as NVGM+N10M. Your explanation seems convincing about the NV10M part. But then what is NVGM?

Comment: No idea. The only reference Google bring out of `NVGM` is a file ( `nvgm.inf` ) which stores the device identifiers of various mobile chipsets so that the drivers can identify them.